# Which 5 items grant max ability power (ap) on any champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

The recipe used to be rather easy and common, stack 5 Archangel's and a Deathcap, but in S3 many things have changed and as I understand it, that's not viable anymore as it doesn't stack, but also due to the reset of the mana pool when an item evolves.

**So my question is, what build of items gets the highest AP in 5v5?
and also for 3v3?**

This should be item specific, without champion specific abilities etc.

My typical [Kassadin build](http://bit.ly/12MbuJ5) yields 787.94 AP and only 4 more AP now if I swap Lich Bane for another Seraph's Embrace.

Note that i'm not sure of the accuracy of the item builder used above, but my typical build in 3v3 Kassadin got me ~732 AP.

When I say typical, I mean what my end game build is, without sacrificing boots for another core item.

Comment: Define core item?

Comment: You might have forgotten setting the runes and masteries, they don't show up when I'm looking at it.

Comment: i meant any damage orientated item, essential to your build.

Comment: odd it didn't save them, but you get the idea. -- fixed and edited

Comment: honestly though, the dfg isnt really worth it, i would much rather take a void staff as my last item, unless the enemy team is being completely stupid and not buying any magic resist whatsoever. In terms of damage you will be doing, being able to ignore 35% of their magic resist with all of your abilities is much better than a single target nuke item. Then again, it would depend on your playstyle, whether you were an assassin or that mage that can walk in and turn the tide of the fight by dropping everyone on the enemy team below half health with one ability. Personally I prefer the latter.

Comment: @Ravekner bad link, don't forget to save. also, i agree depending on the champ, i might not go all ap, but i just want to know what's the new max ever since the change.

Comment: @ericosg Hmmm by just stacking Deathcaps and 1 pair of boots you get 876.91 AP which is already +- 90 AP more then your build. But what is the point tho? Because you are never going to just go for full out AP...

Comment: curiosity and also sometimes you're quickly wondering "what can i take for max ap?"

Comment: pretty sure there is something wrong with that site, can never get my stuff to save and stay saved after reloading

Comment: http://lolcalc.net/b#|c=7;m=3%284%29,6%284%29,10%281%29,8%283%29,13%283%29,14%281%29,17%284%29,18%281%29,38%281%29,40%283%29,44%283%29,41%281%29,47%281%29;r=38%282,9%29,95%282,9%29,71%282,9%29,84%282,3%29;i=30204,3027%2810%29,3089,3157,3001,3040;a=1,5,5,5,3;s=8,9;b=5,3,4,2,0,1;

Comment: @Ravekner there's a rather invisible save button in some screens. :)

Comment: Just keep in mind that... these builds are 100% unviable builds.  As long as it's just a curiosity question you are good to go.  If it is a real game... you will still want a Void staff and boots in exchange for higher AP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going for pure AP, then obviously you want to have a Rabadon's Deathcap. It grants 120 AP, and has a unique passive that modifies your AP up 30%.

Another item you'll almost certainly want is Seraph's Embrace. It only grants 60 AP, but grants 1000 mana, and has a unique passive that grants an additional 3% mana as AP, this makes it worth more than a second Deathcap as soon as you have 1000 mana from other sources.

Lichbane is worth only 87.5 AP, not worth taking in a pure AP build

Rod of Ages is worth about 100 AP, still not worth taking in a pure AP build

Mejai's Soulstealer, fully stacked, is worth 180 AP, definitely worth taking if you can keep the stacks up. It drops to 124 on a single death. (13 stacks)

Deathfire Grasp is worth 120 AP, exactly as much as Rabadon's Deathcap, and would make a good filler item, as while the Active won't stack, you will get the 10% cooldown reduction repeatedly.

Zhonya's Hourglass is also worth 120 AP, and can be stacked for Armour.

Add in Elixer of Brilliance, and Exalted with Baron Nashor for an extra 80 AP and 10% CDR

Final Build: Boots, Rabadon's Deathcap, Seraph's Embrace, Deathfire Grasp, Zhonya's Hourglass, Mejai's Soulstealer. Elixer of Brilliance and Exalted with Baron Nashor.
  =(120+60+120+120+120+40+40+3%mana)*1.3 = (620 + 3% mana) * 1.3 = 884 + 3.9% mana.

This itemization is the best you can do with boots for a generic champion.

This should work for almost any given mana'd champion with any given rune/mastery set. [Here](http://lolcalc.net/b#|c=7;m=1%281%29,3%284%29,6%284%29,10%281%29,8%283%29,13%283%29,17%284%29,18%281%29,40%283%29,38%281%29,44%283%29,43%281%29,47%281%29;r=26%282,9%29,28%282,9%29,27%282,9%29,29%282,3%29;i=3040,3128,3089,3157,3157,30204;a=1,5,5,5,3;s=8%281%29,9;b=2,3;) is a link to this build on Anivia (my main) for 1166 AP

Edit: Sorry, I missed the part about 3v3, That section below:

3v3
Rabadon's Zhonya's, and Mejai's are all disabled, as are Exalted with Baron Nashor and Elixer of Brilliance.

Wooglet's Witchcap, while only 100 AP, multiplies AP by 1.25, and so is still worth taking.

Exalted with Baron Nashor is replaced by Crest of Crushing Wrath, also worth 40 AP, while Elixer of Brilliance is replaced by Ichor of Illumination, which yields 64 AP, up from 40.

Additionally, the 2 altar bonus from Twisted Treeline gives an extra 10% AP. In total the build consisted of 3 Deathfire Grasp's, Seraph's Embrace, Boots, and Wooglet's Witchcap, and I was able to get 1131 AP.

Comment: Considering the base mana and your build, Seraph's Embrace will be more effective at high levels and some champs don't even hit the 1000 mark at level 18, but it's really close. +1

Comment: Don't forget Cooldown reduction is capped at 40% so stacking more then 4 DFG's and some masteries are useless

Comment: @ericosg It seems that most champions that are built with AP have at least 1000, with most having more than 1100+. I've modified the post slightly to be less definitive, but given that I gave the effectiveness threshold, I think it stands.

Comment: @Lyrion well given the case you insist on not taking boots that is ofc a problem, but noone would do that for real (I hope). then you got rabdon (1) seraph(1) boots(1) DFG/Zhonya(3 in any config). and even if you do not want boots you still will never have more than 4 DFG's

Comment: @Vogel612 4 Is to much, because with masteries and maybe runes you get between 9.8 % Cdr and 12.50 % cdr (Depending on flat cdr or cdr/level) So the max you would need to get is 3 DFGS, 1 Rabadon, 1 Zhonya's and Boots. Seraph isn't worth it cause non of the other items give mana.

Comment: @Lyrion also for you here is the link to the base-max mana for each champ:http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions%27_mana  i assume you would want to build a "classic" ap-carry. they all can be found in the section where the base mana on level 18 is higher than 1k, if you now add the 1k from seraph's you will have more than 120 ap on seraph's, which makes it more valuable than 120AP items. the only exceptions where it would not be the case are: fizz, eve, diana and nunu (mb teemo, cho, amu and kayle)

Comment: @Lyrion Vogel is correct, and even on most of those champions, taking three ranks in Expanded Mind mastery in Support gives another 180 mana at 18

Comment: This post should be updated because DFP is no longer in the game and some of the other items have had their AP values changed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the following:

**Twisted Treeline:**
Ability Power: 875 (or 725 with boots)
From 1x Wooglet's Witchcap and 5x Deathfire Grasp

**Summoners Rift:**
Ability Power: 936 (or 780 with boots)
From 1x Rabadon's Deathcap and 5x Deathfire Grasp

Note that in the case of more than 1k mana, Seraph's Embrace yields more AP.
Also note that Deathfire Grasp is interchangeable with any 120 AP item.

The above are without other AP effecting your build (i.e. runes/masteries/abilties).

My Kassadin build would then max to 1038.91.

Comment: note that if someone gets more from some item(s) I missed out i'll edit/delete, but i doubt it. S3 is more clear cut.

Comment: As said in above example 5 DFG's are way to much overkill, you should probably then get Zhonya's for another active and some armor.

Comment: seraph's is worth more ap than DFG, given the case you get over the mark of 2k maximum mana, because from then on the total ap of seraphs break the 120 ap mark (60 + 2000*0.03)

Comment: @Vogel612 yeah, it's very close based on the items and base mana.

Comment: why the -1? please explain

Comment: as seraph's will give you 1k flat and as seen here http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions%27_mana a lot of champs break the 1k mana barrier with the base mana in itself, it can be seen as generic to (classic) ap-carries that seraph's will be 120 ap +

Comment: You need 2k in mana total to have the Seraph's be just equally effective as a 120 ap item. Not more then 1K

Comment: We all refer to 1K existing mana which becomes 2K since SE gives 1K itself.

Answer (score 0):

Rabadons Deathcap
Zhonya's hourglass
Deathfire Grasp
Mejas soul stealer
Rod of Ages or Athene's Unholy Grail or seraphs embrace if charactor run out of mana quick
Sorceror shoes

Comment: Protip: use formatting to make your posts easier to read. I think you will find unordered lists particularly helpful here.

Comment: I don't think those yield max AP, and also those are generic for a good/decent build, a bit unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

it really depends.... if your looking for most damage other items may have more potential than other, higher ap items. Such as if your fizz and your either going for Lich bane or deathfire the lich bane would be more helpful, But this also works the other way round if your playing a champion that doesn't really rely on an item like lich bane such as Katarina where most of her damage is from her ult and high ap ratios then obviously deathfire would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

My main champion is Katarina, and she doesn't rely on mana or energy, so getting mana items would usually be pointless.

I find that Rabadons Deathcap gives the most AP, apart from Mejai's Soulstealer, which gives more than 120 AP at 18 stacks(max stacks).

My usual build is to get a Mejai's first, Zhonya's, Socerers Shoes, Rabadon's, Hextech Gunblade, and any other item you desire.

Answer (score 0):

None of these builds are the highest. Ive made a build with fiddlesticks that ends with 1300 AP.

Build Order:
1. Rod of Ages
2. Mejai's Soulstealer
3. Rabadon's Deathcap
4. Archangel's Staff
5. Rod of Ages
6. Rod of Ages

Flat Ap total: 890
With Max Stacks: about 1100+

Other perks that lead to 1300 AP:
Baron kill
5 dragons
Elixir of sorcery
Runes and masteries

Why this works:
1. Rod of ages' passive is NOT unique, so its stacks can reach up to 30 between three rods.
2. Not only does ROA give AP per stack, it also gives lots of mana, even with NO stacks, which gives even more AP from seraph's embrace.
3. As a side note, even though this is a late game build, it grants a character great early game survivability from the health bonus given from the 3 ROAs (3271 on the build i used with no stacks)
4. Although its true that building magic pen is crucial on AP characters, the massive health, mana, and AP from this build can turn any character into an AP Tank of Death

Comment: Although It 's a viable build to answer the question.
Building 3 Rod of ages is just not viable in a real (rank) game. Or you would need to actually build the 3 rod of ages in under 30 minutes to hope having the full benefit of them.
Nice build though for AP Trolling!

Comment: ROA is gold efficient with no stacks, it is viable to build 6 ROA on some champions, say Ryze, Singed or Blitzcrank. Not the best possible strategy but it's viable.